# how to I create a media query for mobile site stylesheet?

Tags: redirect, mobile, media-queries, directory-structure

I have previously been told to use something along the lines of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css">
```

I'd like to use a separate stylesheet AND html doc for mobile visitors. Is that normal? I have so many elements I want cut from the mobile version it seemed less complicated to just have a site within a site for mobile - it's own html and CSS.

How do I use the media query above for a mobile specific stylesheet and for an html? What code would I use and where would I put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link href="the/directory/containing/your/mobile.css type="text/css" media="handheld" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Next line could be:

```
<link href="the/directory/containing/your/desktop.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Use this method and avoid two documents. Instead you're styling one document according to the device being used to view that document.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you have to detect the browser server side, and serve up a different page.

PHP pseudocode example

```
if(browser == mobile && !isset($_COOKIES["prefer_desktop_view"])) //Pseudo code you do the checking here
{
   $_COOKIES["is_mobile"] = true; //more pseudo code
   header("location: mobile.example.com") //redirect solution - if
}
```

Media queries are CSS specific. There's no way to do this on the client side, and even if there was, the client still has to download and parse the "desktop" HTML.

Comment: Thanks fo your answer. I have no experience in programming, only basic html, css and some very basic JS. Are you telling me that with my knowledge I must use the same html doc as I have no way of redirecting traffic to a separate html doc? The code above - could I cut n paste that? What would the file be? Just .php? Would I put it in root folder?

Comment: No, you can't copy and paste pseudocode.

If you do it 100% client side, you could do something with "Responsive design", but it would require the phones you're targeting support CSS3 - most smart phones do.